# Как сохранить записи в таблице при перемещении её между приложениями Django?

Tags: python, django

Есть модель Document в одном из аппов, я её перемещаю в другой апп и называю Contract. Как мне не потерять записи при перемещении? Как грамотно написать кастомную миграцию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено. Достаточно провести подобную миграцию перед удалением таблицы Document

```
from django.db import migration

def migrate_existing_rows(apps, schema_editor):
    document = apps.get_model("accounts", "Document")
    contract = apps.get_model("contracts", "Contract")
    alias = schema_editor.connection.alias

    for doc in document.objects.all():
        contract.objects.using(alias).create(
            title = doc.title,
            file = doc.file,
            tenant = doc.renter,
            object = doc.object
        )


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ("accounts", "0025_add_issue_create_date"),
        ("contracts", "0001_initial"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(migrate_existing_rows)
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Записи хранятся в **sqlite3** или в подключённой вами **базе данных**.

Если вы хотите получить данные из **sqlite3**:
1. Делаете *dump* текущих данных (получаете *.json):
`python manage.py dumpdata > projectdata.json`

2. Подключаете необходимую вам БД в настройках вашего проекта.

3. Переходите в *dbshell* 
`python manage.py dbshell`
`=> TRUNCATE django_content_type CASCADE;`

4. Загружаете дамп в проект:
`python manage.py loaddata projectdata.json`

Если вы хотите получить данные из другой **подключенной базы данных** - воспользуйтесь встроенными средствами этой базы данных.

Comment: Вы неправильно поняли. Я не меняю БД, я перемещаю таблицу между приложениями

Comment: Какая у вас БД используется?

Comment: Я использую PostgeSQL

Comment: Смотрите вы можете перенести таблицу встроенными способами: для этого почитайте о `migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState` (сам лично с этим дел не имел). Или другой способ, сейчас опишу.

Comment: В новом _app_ создаёте модель подобную вашей. Делаете миграции. А далее уже в самом _Postgres_ находите ваши две таблицы и переименовываете их наоборот.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, но у меня получилось обойтись простенькой кастомной миграцией

Comment: Могу ваш способ увидеть?

Comment: Я добавил его как ответ к вопросу